# Div to toggle between fade in and out when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my fade menu div to fade in when the menu button is clicked and fade out when the menu button is clicked again. I have followed several other tutorials and researched other questions on this but I cant get anything to work properly. After refreshed the div is already visible and clicking the menu button does nothing. Here's my code -

```
  <!-- MENU BUTTON HAMBURGER -->
  <button class="menu-button" id="toggle">
      <span class="hamburger"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- ====== MENU ====== -->
  <div id="fade-menu">
      <span id="temporary-space"></span>
  </div>
```

---

```
var toggle = $('#toggle');
var menu = $('#fade-menu');

toggle.click(function() {
    menu.fadeToggle(1000, function() {

    });
});
```

Comment: Your code should be working fine. `After refreshed the div is already visible` - browser does not keep elements state by default. You have to use some localstorage/session/cookies for state saving.

Comment: What version of jQuery you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is disable the effect where when you click several times, it fade over and over again, just disable the button during the fad effect as following :

```
<!-- MENU BUTTON HAMBURGER -->
<button class="menu-button" id="toggle">
    <span class="hamburger">toggle</span>
</button>

<!-- ====== MENU ====== -->
<div id="fade-menu">
    <span id="temporary-space">test</span>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // without saving the menu state
        var toggle = $('#toggle');
        var menu = $('#fade-menu');
        toggle.click(function() {
            toggle.prop('disabled', true);
        menu.fadeToggle(1000, function() {
            toggle.prop('disabled', false);
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

If what you need is save the state of the toggle (if visible or not), then tell me i'll give you a piece of code with localstorage.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed. Yes I want it initially to be invisible when the page loads and fade in/out when button clicked like code above.

Comment: then, just add : `style="display: none;"` to the `fade-menu` div as following : `<div id="fade-menu" style="display: none;">`